# Configuring Django in local dev environment to work with imported MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, model, localhost

I usually use SQLite but this project requires me to use data from a server so instead of trying to convert the data from SQLite to MySQL, I imported the data into my local MySQL database. I am trying to figure out how to configure my Django project to work with the imported database. Right now the models.py file is empty.

So I have three questions:

1. Is my settings.py (below) set up correctly?
2. Do I need to set up the models to match the schema in the imported
       database?
3. Do I need to do anything else?

This is what I'm working with:

- Django 1.8.4
- Python 2.7
- mysql 5.7.14
- osx 10.11

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

"""..."""

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'extract',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '22',
    }
}
""" ... """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `./manage.py inspectdb` after mentioning mysql database in settings.py. have a look at docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Would I just copy the output from that command to my models.py file?

Comment: Yes you may. Also have a look at `Meta` section of models. Its informative. If your issue is solved you may mark this as accepted answer. :)